# How do I validate an email address with an if statement while removing the built-in validation?

Tags: php

In my form I have a list item with an input type of "email".
Well the problem with this is whenever I do not enter a valid email address in the input box, a pop-up shows up saying, "Please enter an email address."  So my question is how do I remove this pop-up and apply my own validation??
I tried putting novalidate = "novalidate" in the form, and that removed the pop-up, BUT I believe that's affecting my "if statement" because it is not working to validate the email address.  All my other "if statements" are working except for the one I wrote in the code below.
Here's a simple layout of my code:

```
<form action ="" novalidate="novalidate" method="post">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <input type="email" name="email">
        </li>
    </ul>
</form>

<?php
    if (empty($errors) === true) {
        if (filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $errors[] = 'A valid email address is required.';
        }
?>
```

Comment: PHP won't cause a pop-up. Sounds like you're using some sort of client side validation?

Comment: It's not the php.  It's the html5 form.  It has built-in validation and it causes the popup whenever a valid email address isn't entered for an input type of email.

Comment: @KacyRaye please see my answer. I think it achieves what you're looking for...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `if()` statement will only execute if a **valid** email is entered. You need to reverse the logic inside the statement, whilst also keeping the `novalidate` parameter inside the `<form>`:

```
<form action="" novalidate="novalidate" method="post">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <input type="email" name="email">
        </li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

Your PHP should look like this:

```
<?php
if(empty($errors) === true) 
{
    if(!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) 
    {
        $errors[] = 'A valid email address is required.';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you very much! 
It says I can't accept the answer for another 4 minutes but I'll be sure to do so the second it lets me!